# Apache NIFI - Build from source

Tags: maven, apache-nifi

I'm trying to prepare a build o NIFI on ubuntu.
I base on instruction from:
https://github.com/apache/nifi

First, i cloned repository
git clone https://gitbox.apache.org/repos/asf/nifi.git
I have lastest maven version. Java is up to date to(21)

and next i started build creation:

```
./mvnw clean install -T2C -DskipTests
```

But i get error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> com.github.spotbugs:spotbugs-maven-plugin:4.7.3.5:spotbugs (spotbugs)
> on project nifi-xml-processing: Execution spotbugs of goal
> com.github.spotbugs:spotbugs-maven-plugin:4.7.3.5:spotbugs failed:
> Java returned: 1 -> [Help 1] [ERROR] [ERROR] To see the full stack
> trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. [ERROR] Re-run
> Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

Any idea?
Can i bypass this specific plugin and go forward?

Comment: Is your SpotBugs up to date? Do we know whether it supports Java 21 yet? If you can skip this step, it should certainly be OK to do.

Comment: SpotBugs is up to date
https://spotbugs.github.io/spotbugs-maven-plugin/#please-note-this-version-is-using-spotbugs-4-7-3
There is information
Please Note

"As of version 3.1.0, you will need to use JDK 8 to run this plugin. This is a requirement imposed by Spotbugs."

But for apache nifi i have:
Minimum Requirements

    JDK 21
    Apache Maven 3.9.2


Sadly i don't see option to skip this step :/